Shared DLL built with -shared doesnt have any symbols from the source file
I'm trying to build a DLL of https://github.com/littledivy/duckdb/raw/master/src/sql.c on Windows:
clang src/sql.c -O3 -shared -o bin/libduckdb.dll -lduckdb -L"C:\projects\deno-duckdb-master\bin" -I"C:\projects\deno-duckdb-master\include"

When trying to load the DLL with Deno.dlopen, it fails to find any of the duckffi_* symbols.
Opening the DLL with Dependencies shows only the symbols from the duckdb.dll, but none from sql.c


I think you should be adding the dllexport attribute to the things you want to export...

~Added __declspec(dllexport), it now generates a .dll, .lib and .exp. But Dependencies still shows no symbols on the DLL~ Never mind, Deno recognizes the symbols now, despite not showing up in Dependencies
